# classic ASP write session using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, asp-classic

I have a Facebook Javascript that reports if a user is logged in and i want to store a session variable so that i can tell my site that the user is logged in. here it the script.

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
   var uid = response.authResponse.userID; --> want to store this in a session variable
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; --> want to store this in a session variable
 } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
// the user is logged in to Facebook, 
// but has not authenticated your app
 } else {
  alert("your not connected");
}
});
 };
```

Comment: The code you posted is nasty looking. Could you please edit it and format it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fire an AJAX request to the server, passing the `accessToken`, then store it on the session from your ASP code on the server. You can't do that directly from client-side js (but you can set cookies).

Comment: Sorry, but I can't write you a step by step explanation on how to do that. Most importantly, you have to understand that ASP code runs on the server, prepares the page and then send it to the browser. Only then javascript code runs. So to be able to have js code talk to the server (Sessions live on the server), you have to fire a new http request to the server, asynchronously, using ajax. There are plenty of ajax tutorials on the web, including here on stackoverflow. If you've never used ajax before, maybe you should look for js libraries to make your life easier, like jQuery.